# Video autoplayed - ContainerView - Switching between views - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview, segmentedcontrol

I have an [`HMSegmentedControl`](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl) used for switching between segments. I used container view to switch between these segments, which works fine, but one of my tabs have a video that is autoplayed on `viewDidAppear`. So my problem is that as container view loads everything prior and shows views depending on `isHidden = false`, my video starts playing even if that segment isn't selected. How can I go about this situation?

This is my code on `segmentedControlValueChanged` event

```
print("selected index \(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)")

    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        liveContainer.isHidden = true
    case 1:
        liveContainer.isHidden = true
    case 2:
        liveContainer.isHidden = false
    default:
        break
    }
```

Comment: Can you put your code snippet here?

Comment: When do you want to play the video?

Comment: Once the tab/segment's page is visible

Comment: So why are you autoplaying the video?? Just pause the video and play it on segment change.

Comment: I have written the code to load it in viewDidAppear but it just starts playing before I click that corresponding segment

Comment: So you can pause it in viewDidAppear and resume when segment is changed.

Comment: How can I find out when the view is visible?

Comment: Check `view.superview?.isHidden` flag in view controller.

Comment: @IgorBidiniuc Thanks:) It takes me one step closer. But the problem is that viewDidAppear isn't called once the view is shown so where do I write this then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to send notification to the view controller that contains the video when it is shown/hidden to play/stop the video. This can be done in the container view segment selection. So, you can remove autoplay from `viewDidAppear` and add it to the method called when the notification is sent.

For example, in your `segmentedControlValueChanged` event, you can write:

```
switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
case 0:
    liveContainer.isHidden = true
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("StopVideo"), object: nil)
case 1:
    liveContainer.isHidden = true
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("StopVideo"), object: nil)
case 2:
    liveContainer.isHidden = false
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("PlayVideo"), object: nil)
default:
    break
}
```

and in your video `ViewController`, you can have two methods: one for playing video:

```
func playVideo() {
  //play video here
}
```

and another for stopping it:

```
func stopVideo() {
  //stop video here
}
```

and in your video `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, you can add observers:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playVideo), name: "PlayVideo", object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(stopVideo), name: "StopVideo", object: nil)
```

Comment: Please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSNotificationCenter`.

On Receiving File:

In `-viewDidLoad:`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"NOTIFICATIONID" object:nil];
```

And Create method to receive Notification.

```
-(void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"NOTIFICATIONID"])
    {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSNumber* segmentID = (NSNumber*)userInfo[@"segmentID"];
        NSLog (@"Successfully received test notification! %i", segmentID.intValue);
    }
}
```

To post Notification:

```
NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"segmentID": @(segmentID)}; //Used to pass Objects to Notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATIONID" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

Disable you current autoplaying. And just play your video when you receive notification. Post notification only when you select the segment.

Comment: Both these methods are called even if my view is hidden

Comment: No. Please give me an example